# Query postgress en mysql DJANGO

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, django-models

buen día, tengo un problema.
Quiero usar un query que tengo en postgres pero no me funciona con mysql obviamente////////////
La idea es que quiero restar ciertas cantidades y salvarlas sobre el mismo registro.
El error es que al consultar la tabla, no se resta el self.debt.
Sin arrojar ningun error si le agrego o imprimo algun exception

LES DEJO MI CODIGO de mi view:

```
            elif action == 'add':
                with transaction.atomic():
                    payment = PaymentsDebtsPay()
                    payment.debtspay_id = int(request.POST['debtspay'])
                    payment.date_joined = request.POST['date_joined']
                    payment.valor = float(request.POST['valor'])
                    payment.desc = request.POST['desc']
                    if len(payment.desc) == 0:
                        payment.desc = 'Sin detalles'
                    payment.save()
                    payment.debtspay.validate_debt()
            else:
                data['error'] = 'No ha ingresado una opción'
```

Y este es mi codigo en mi model:

```
    def validate_debt(self):
        try:
            saldo = self.paymentsdebtspay_set.aggregate(resp=Coalesce(Sum('valor'), 0.00)).get('resp')
            self.saldo = float(self.debt) - float(saldo)
            self.state = self.saldo > 0.00
            self.save()
        except:
            pass
```

Quedo atento a sus comentarios. Saludos!

Comment: Nada es obvio en este lugar ;) Qué falla cuando lo intentas portar a postgresql? Qué intentaste hacer para que funcione? Qué error encuentras? La idea del sitio no es que hagan el porting por ti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO.
En django 3.2 al usar Coalesce se debe de agregar output_field=FloatField()

```
saldo = self.paymentsdebtspay_set.aggregate(
                resp=Coalesce(Sum('valor'), 0.00, output_field=FloatField())).get('resp')
```